# Creating a ResourceKey in XAML WPF and how to find my namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to put some colour into a lousy ListView, I found that [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/ms750769(v=vs.85)) (method 1 specifically) which tells me to define a ResourceKey with this:

```
<namespc:BackgroundConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>
```

Despite said resource failing to mention it, I figured `namespc` was a placeholder and that this bit of code had to go in a `<UserControl.Resources>` block.

The problem is I don't know how to make that ResourceKey stick. If I leave `namespc`, it tells me the namespace doesn't exist. I've seen answers that use `local` or `super`, which also produce the error. I've tried putting my namespace `RechercheArchive` (which is were the BackgroundConverter class is located), and obviously I wouldn't be here if it worked.

Therefore my XAML currently looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RechercheArchive.SearchTab"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="900">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <namespc:BackgroundConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>

        <Style x:Key="myItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"
                             Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid> 
    <!-- Bunch of stuff --> 
    <Grid/>
</UserControl>
```

What am I missing here?

PS: If you have a better title for this, feel free to throw suggestions.

---

EDIT: For posterity, here's what solved my problem.

So, the namespace problem was solved by adding

```
xmlns:namespc="clr-namespace:RechercheArchive"
```

as such

```
<UserControl x:Class="RechercheArchive.SearchTab"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:namespc="clr-namespace:RechercheArchive"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="900">
```

But wait, there's more. The resource didn't implement a `ConvertBack` method on the converter and Visual Studio failed to raise an error. So make sure you implement `IValueConverter` properly I guess.

Comment: `namespc` is a XML/XAML namespace declaration, like `xmlns:namespc="clr-namespace:YourApplication"`.

Comment: @Clemens Okay, I've added `xmlns:namespc="clr-namespace:RechercheArchive"` to the `<UserControl>` tag, but now I get "BackgroundConverter" does not exist in "clr-namespace:RechercheArchive". Autocompletion finds the class, but it still won't build. I'll add it's a public sealed class like indicated in the resource.

Comment: RechercheArchive should be the CLR namespace in which the Converter class is declared. Then rebuilt the project.

Comment: @Clemens Turns out you are right, VS found another error, namely that the converter needs a ConvertBack method. So that was another critical step missing from the guide.

Comment: @Clemens Anyways, thanks for nudging my in the right direction.